# Grails JSON convertor is not serialising embedded child objects

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I upgraded my project from grails 2.3.4 to 2.3.8 and conversion of embedded JSON objects stopped working

I'm using MongoDB as the only persistence.

Following is my code structure.

```
// Post class
class Post {
    String id
    String title
    String content
    List comments

    static embedded = ['comments']
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]

}

//Comments class
class Comment {
    String name
    String email
    String website
    String content
}

//code in controller
class PostController {
    def show() {
        def postInstance = Post.collection.findOne(title: id)
        postInstance = postInstance as Post
        log.info "Post comments with id {postInstance.comments.name}"

        respond postInstance
    }
}

//log details
INFO Post comments with id [Hussain1, Hussain2]

//JSON Response
{
    "class": "com.Post",
    "id": "5364be6703647a4cd37dd293",
    "comments": [
        {
            "class": "com.Comment",
            "id": null
        },
        {
            "class": "com.Comment",
            "id": null
        }
    ],
    "content": "Content",
    "title": "This-is-a-title"
}
```

Any idea why the child objects in JSON objects are not coming properly similar thing was working in Grails 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

You’re rendering the BSONObject from MongoDB rather than the domain instance, is that intentional? If so check the data you actually have stored in your Post document collection. Otherwise file a jira at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB and attach an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi Graeme I tried both ways fetching BSONObject and domain instance using Post.findByTitle(id). Same result in both cases I'll create a sample project report in JIRA.

Comment: Graeme, I have filed a jira with a sample project https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-373